# 2 Questions in a set defined in proof of Cauchy Theorem of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am self studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford and I couldn't understand proof of this theorem on page 93 .

Adding it's image :

[image]

> I have  question in 2nd paragraph of Proof of Theorem 5.2 .1.How to prove that $(a_{1} ,..., a_{p} ) \in S_{0} $ iff $a_{1} =... = a_{p} $ .

2. How does the argument that $|S_{0} |$ has at least p elements implies there exists a$\neq$ e such that (a,..., a) $\in S_{0} $ .

I am unable to derive both results despite thinking a lot , so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, note that the action of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ on $S$ is by cyclic rotation. In other words, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, the action of $k$ on a tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_p)$ rotates the coordinates by $k$ places to the left (and cycling around to the end), to produce $(a_{k+1},\ldots,a_{p},a_1,\ldots,a_k)$. So clearly if $a_1=\ldots=a_p$ then the resulting tuple is invariant under this action, and thus in $S_0$. For the other direction, if $(a_1,\ldots,a_p)\in S_0$ (i.e., the tuple is invariant under the action), then all coordinates must be the same. Indeed, if some $a_i\neq a_j$ then we can find an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ which rotates the tuple to put $a_i$ in the $j$th position, resulting in a distinct tuple.

For the second question, if $|S_0|\geq p$ then, in particular, there is more than one tuple in $S_0$. So there is a tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_p)$ in $S_0$ that is *not* $(e,\ldots,e)$. But we already showed that tuples in $S_0$ are "constant". So this tuple must be of the form $(a,\ldots,a)$ for some $a\neq e$.